# Android: Exception calling an AsyncTask in a Notification

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a notification at a specific time which is choosen by user. This notification makes a call of an AsyncTask which is in another class. I'm getting an exception every time I call that AsyncTask with this code:

```
new ExtendedActivity().new Parse().getHoroscope("daily", signo);
```

I have put `Log.d` on getHoroscope but the exception I get is before it.

The exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.converter.android.dailyhoroscope.MyReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2732)                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
                                                                                            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:150)                                                                                       at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:110)                                                                                        at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:222)                                                                                        at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:200)                                                                                       at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:196)                                                                                        at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:141)                                                                                        at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)                                                                                       at com.converter.android.dailyhoroscope.ExtendedActivity$Parse.<init>(ExtendedActivity.java:73)                                                                                       at com.converter.android.dailyhoroscope.MyReceiver.createNotification(MyReceiver.java:89)                                                                                        at com.converter.android.dailyhoroscope.MyReceiver.onReceive(MyReceiver.java:60)                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2725)                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

SchedulerActivity.java

```
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

MyReceiver.java

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
 (...)
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    signo  = pref.getString(dHosocope,"");
    createNotification(context, signo);
}

public void createNotification(Context context, String signo){
(...)
   sentence = new ExtendedActivity().new Parse().getHoroscope("daily", signo);
}
```

Class Extended

```
public class ExtendedActivity extends BaseActivity {

//AsyncThread
    public class Parse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
      public String getHoroscope(String type, String option){
        String description="", site;
        Log.d("Extended","inside getHoroscopes");
        (...)
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call new Activity().  The only way to create an Activity is via startActivity().  Any other attempt will cause errors, either immediately or later on.  If you need that AsyncTask to be used outside the Activity, make it a top level class not an inner class.